# Bootstrap 4 vertical align not working at all for me

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is code that I directly copied and pasted from Bootstrap's documentation. And for some reason when I use it (with 2 columns), the first column center aligns vertically to the height of the second column. And nothing changes no matter the height of the parent element. Is there something I am doing wrong? I also have included the code I am trying to use. I am look for both columns to vertically align into the center of the containing element.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm pink"></div>
    <div class="col-sm pink"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explicity says what element you want to vertical align inside what other element?

Comment: *"And nothing changes no matter the height of the parent element."* .. Do you have code that demonstrates this? What is the height of the parent element?